# How to customize response object in Bookshelf JS?

Tags: javascript, express, bookshelf.js

I want to add a custom property to the standard Bookshelf.js response object. In this case, the goal is to `fetchAll()` Regions and append the property `link` to each Region. The value of link is simply `/some/api/route/${region.id}`.

I believe there are two ways to achieve this: (1) modify to the Regions model to include some function `getRegionLink()` to generate the desired value; or (2) iterate over and modify the response object. I think that (1) is preferred, but I can imagine when (2) may be necessary.

With that context, I haven't been able to figure out how to do (2). The [Bookshelf.js docs](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-subsection-lodash-methods) state that _.each() is available, though the [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#forEach) deprecated each in favor of forEach. However, the following did not work as expected. Some error occurs. On a related note, the `err` objects log empty on Postman.

**Region Service**

```
Region.forge()
    .fetchAll()
    .then(regions => {
      _.forEach(regions, region => {
        region.link = `${API_BASE}/location/regions/v1/${region.id}`;
      });
      res.json(regions);
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(404).json(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The core of this question is answered by the ["virtuals" plugin for Bookshelf](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Virtuals). Related post: [Bookshelf.js set attribute not in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425746/bookshelf-js-set-attribute-not-in-database)